# Import an unexported interface from an unexported namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way you can import an un-exported interface from an un-exported namespace?

I want to import interfaces from here: https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/master/src/typings/spotify-api.d.ts

Thanks

[Edit]

Turns out, you don't need to import the namespace, you can just reference it in your code e.g.

```js
const foo: SpotifyApi.TheInterfaceYouWantToImport = {bar: 'baz'}
```

I would appreciate if someone could link me to the section in the Typescript docs that explains how this works.

Comment: I don't see other way to do it than editing the source and exporting the namespace / interface required.

Comment: Will exporting the namespace alone suffice?

Comment: Not a big fan of namespaces (I hate them), but if I skimmed the docs correctly, it seems that you can just put your code into the same namespace and then consume the interfaces without exporting them: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces

Comment: I guess you mean: "without importing them". How do I put my code inside the namespace? I assume that just by doing a single import from the library, the namespaces are imported. It actually worked for me without importing SpotifyApi, which is a bit weird. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, I mean you don't have to change anything in the API specification, you just enclose your code in `namespace SpotifyApi  {}`. And by the way I see now that this is just another unoficial typings declaration that just adds types an existing JS API. So sorry, but do you know how to work with typings ?

Comment: Yes. Just a bit behind on namespaces. I guess I have to read the namespaces docs thoroughly

Comment: ESlint screams at me when I wrap my code with the namespace keyword. It says I should use modules instead. Which doesn't really make sense when it comes to my problem.

Comment: Well then probably just edit the type definitions so that you can access the unexported APIs.

Comment: It worked by just referencing the namespace alone (without doing any imports) i.e. Spotify.Api. At which point did Typescript recognize the SpotifyApi word in my code as the namespace it's referring to? Just by having it in node_modules? Importing from the module once? I can't find any info on that in the docs.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it and sorry for misleading you. Saddly I don't know if the `.d.ts` files get any special treatment from `tsc`. I just happily use them. Maybe you should edit your question so that others know how to proceed.

Comment: It's alright, thanks for your help. Will do.

Comment: Consider removing the edit of your post and post it as an answer. It will help other devs that have similar issues

Comment: It's not a proper answer Imo. A proper answer should have an explanation of how and why this works.